# Please clarify "score" vs. "reputation" on tag badge descriptions

Tags: feature-request, badges

I just started writing this question,

> I was just notified that I just got the Java bronze badge.
>
> The description says
>
> > Earned at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki
> >     answers in the java tag.
>
> As you can see, I have 2061 reputation, almost all of it earned in the
>   Java---

then realized my mistake. I had confused reputation with question score.

Can you please make this clear in the tag badge description?

Comment: What would you suggest? (please not "at least 100 total score (*not reputation*) ")

Comment: I'm not sure I see what needs to be clarified...you even realize the mistake of conflating score with reputation.

Comment: @Shog9 yes, actually something like that. "at least 100 total score *(not to be confused with reputation)*" If the idea is stupid, I withdraw it :-).

Comment: How about "earned at least 100 net upvotes"? I assume that accepted answers aren't counted towards the score.

Comment: @samgak That's a lot better.

Comment: @samgak A downvote is not *really* an anti-upvote: a cancelled upvote is an anti-upvote.  "earned at least 100 net vote score".  Or "earned at least 100 net signed votes" (which is obtuse, but I'm not sure if there is an invalid interpretation).

Comment: @Yakk I actually think just replacing "score" with "net votes"/"votes" would be an improvement.

Comment: @k_g If you get 50 downvotes and 50 upvotes, you have 100 total votes.  And that won't get you the badge.  :)

Comment: @Yakk net votes then? I don't think most people would immediately think "net unsigned votes"...

Comment: [Cross site duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188260/clarify-what-score-means-in-badge-descriptions)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I think "net upvotes" would be a lot clearer than "total score".

Comment: I disagree. If you post a candidate answer as a comment you're clearly the one doing it wrong

Comment: If possible, "net upvotes" could be a link to provide a clear definition (or have an appropriate tooltip).

Comment: Why "Net"?  Why not just "Upvotes"?

Comment: Because the "score" (or "net upvotes") is computed as upvotes minus downvotes.

Comment: @user Normally, I would agree with you regarding posting candidate answers as comments, but there's not really a question in the OP, so it's not really possible to have a true answer in this case. Unless you count "Can you do this?" as a question, in which case this doesn't directly answer it.

Comment: I've fallen into this trap too.  *Please* change the wording.

Answer (score -6):

Just translate score into reputation and be done with it. **Score is lame.** I have to learn a new term for what?!

- Earned at least 1000 reputation for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the [some-decent-language-that-isnt-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/some-decent-language-that-isnt-java) tag.

Comment: The main meaningful difference is that score, unlike reputation, doesn't include accepts.

Comment: Then change it to include accepts. This game doesn't need the complex rule set. Diablo II was good. Diablo III was overkill. This thing is going FULL DIABLO. Never go FULL DIABLO.

Comment: "Then change it to include accepts" -- [A discussion of such a proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300532/2751851), though the OP there had different motives, and therefore that proposal doesn't actually try to simplify the system.