# Answer acceptance to count toward tag score

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, tag-score

Your score in a given tag is based solely on the number of votes you have received on answers tagged with that tag.

Based on this system, it would be possible to have 100 accepted answers in `TagA`, and a score of 0 in `TagA`.

In low traffic tags, it's very possible for this kind of situation to arise, in fact it's almost a certainty.

Now, rep-whoring aside, the accumulation of tag score, along with the awarding of tag badges is not only a goal to aim for, but is also a good indication of expertise within a certain area.

Someone who has many, many accepted answers in a tag would be correctly classified as something of an expert in that tag. However their actual tag score could be some very low number (even zero).

Stack Overflow currently recognizes the contribution of these users by awarding the **Tenacious** and **Unsung Hero** badges, however, these are not tag specific, so do little to address this imbalance in my opinion.

My proposal would be for an accepted answer count as a +1 to the tag score.

The +1 should only accrue if the awarder does not also upvote:

- accepted answer = +1
- upvote = +1
- accepted answer + upvote = +1

Who's with me?

Comment: Shouldn't an accepted answer be worth more than an upvote?

Comment: @Loko usually OP will already up-vote, so his vote then counts for 2. That seems fair to me.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I just mean in general. Accepted answers also give you more rep than an upvote. Also you cant really assume OP will upvote too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman A new user can accept an answer but can't upvote without 15 rep.

Comment: @DavidPostill I know. So that would still be +1 on your tag score for new users. +2 for up-vote and accept.

Comment: Hmm... it looks like this change would give the original poster one or two silver tag badges and one or two bronze tag badges. Overall it would increase his badge score by about 50%. Personally, I'd only gain one more bronze tag badge with an over all increase in badge score of about 40%.

Comment: As someone with the Unsung Hero badge, I approve of this message.

Comment: hah. I just checked.. I have 9... wonderful. But still this is an interesting thought. Would love to hear a counter thought.

Comment: 9 answers with a score of 0 and accepted. 10 is the base for UnsungHero

Comment: @CayceK: Actually, it's 11.

Comment: 11 for the [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) or 11 answers at 0 for me that have been accepted? Because unless I'm really, really bad at  math and adding (which is not out of question yet) I'm pretty sure I currently have 9. :D

Comment: @Loko Yes, this one: "Shouldn't an accepted answer be worth more than an upvote?" If you realized afterward that it's true, then it's superfluous/obsolete and shouldn't remain.

Comment: "I feel accepted answers are a fine social contract, but not a good data point for question or answer quality..." ([Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/165773))

Comment: @TylerH Now I'm wondering if you understood the question correctly. This is about tag score, not reputation. OP says: *My proposal would be for an accepted answer count as a +1 to the tag score.* That means with tag score an accepted answer would be the same as 1 upvote. Thats why I asked that question.

Comment: So there is no feedback from the "authorized one" here? Should I flag it for attention?

Comment: @UlukBiy yes please if you don't mind...

Comment: I'd prefer "accepted answer + upvote by anyone = +1". Let the asker's vote remain private.

Comment: Why is this legitimate question, which seems to be approved by many here, has not received an answer from SO staff yet?

Comment: Is there a way to draw admin attention to this post? There's a clear need, a simple proposal which has no opposition ("Accepted answers with zero votes count as +1"), which would presumably be simple to implement. And no comment from any SO staff (afaik).

Comment: I support this. how to get enough attention to this thread?

Comment: Any update? I have a lot of accepted zero score answers (unsung hero tag) because I try to answer to a lot of new users with no experience with stack overflow :(

Comment: Why isn't this still not implemented even after 5 years and 9 months ??

Comment: I seriously see no sense in your proposal: I would simply say: "accepted answer = +1, upvote = +1, accepted answer + upvote = +2".

Comment: Why is this still not implemented after 8 years and 5 months? It only makes sense.

Answer (score 42):

I support this, although it'll be better that a +1 will be awarded if an accepted answer has 0 or less score. This way there will be no "extra" points for all accepts, just for those that classify for "Unsung hero" badge. Just add sum of accepted answers under a given tag that have 0 or less score to the amount of "tag score".

Comment: I would certainly support this.

Comment: So this would mean that a 0 score accepted answer gives the same as a +1 accepted answer?

Comment: @Loko Yes, effectively equalizing answering questions for those users that can't upvote with those which OPs can upvote. Reputation gain will still be different, but tag proficiency will progress even if OPs cannot upvote.

Comment: _"+1 will be awarded if an accepted answer has 0 or less score"_ -- so in other words, if a questioner accepts a bad answer, that will actually _reward_ the answerer? This proposal has "unintended harmful consequences" written all over it. And frankly, it seems like a worse version of the heavily-downvoted proposal I gave (i.e. grant the +1 toward the badge for an accepted answer, but only if the person posting the question didn't up-vote the answer).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Acceptance indicates the answer was helpful and solved the problem, regardless of its score. I would downvote a CSS answer that said not much more than "use `!important` with the property" because it is low quality and bad advice, but if the asker tries and finds that it works (it probably would), then the asker is well within their right to accept that answer. Votes are a reflection of an answer's perceived value by the community, but acceptance is currently solely the purview of the asker.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "Bad" answer? There might be no one around to say the answer is actually good, not even the asker (they had 1 rep, haha). This is indeed the case with low-traffic tags (I had a silver in AS3 in almost three years and 500+ answers, and about half of them were not upvoted by anyone, while many were accepted). And for high-traffic tags, peer review will quickly downhill an accepted answer if it's really bad, resulting in negative tag score gain. So I propose a balanced (IMO) solution that impacts low-traffic tags better than high-traffic tags.

Comment: @PeterDuniho How come it's a floor? It's a net +1 for acceptance if an accepted answer has 0 or less. That is, if an answer has -2, and has been accepted, its net value in total tag score (each tag) will be -1 against -2 right now. No "floor of +1".

Comment: Sorry...your proposal wasn't stated clearly. It appeared to me you were setting the vote _value_ to +1. That said, with your clarification, your proposal is nearly the same as the one I already made, except that you would allow the poster of a question to effectively double-vote for an answer. I.e. you would award the extra vote even if the question poster had already up-voted the answer; while this is not quite as bad as setting a floor, it still has the similar effect of preferentially rewarding bad answers, just to a lesser degree.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry for vague explanations. In fact, this system does not allow the asker to double-vote, unless someone else would downvote, because if the asker would upvote, the answer will have a score of 1 and thus not eligible for an extra point for being accepted.

Comment: _"unless someone else would downvote"_ -- that's my point. Your proposal is specifically boosting the score of the answer exactly when others have already indicated it's a bad answer. It also fails to award the extra vote even when the questioner _hasn't_ up-voted the answer while anyone else has. So bad answers (those with downvotes) tend to be rewarded, while good answers (those with upvotes) tend not to be. Granted, the effect is small, but a) so is the effect of the _lack_ of any change, and b) whatever the magnitude of the effect, it's rewarding and punishing exactly the wrong behaviors.

Answer (score 29):

The following proposal was made by Peter Duniho. Regardless of what people think about the other views expressed in his answer, I feel this proposal should stand on its own, because I see it as a cleaner and better solution than the currently leading answer.

> An acceptance of an answer should be counted toward the tag badge *only* if the questioner did not also up-vote the answer (i.e. don't double-count the input from the questioner).

This would give the questioner an opportunity to contribute their +1 to the tag score, regardless of whether they use an upvote or accept to do that.

It wouldn't have the undesired effect of counting the questioner's input twice for answers with score <= 0, or *not* counting their accept if they can't vote and the answer has a positive score.

Comment: Whilst I agree with Peter's point above, and would certainly support it, his manner of argument thereafter was incredibly patronising.

Answer (score 9):

The whole reputation system is already biased towards high-traffic tags and it would be rather difficult to remedy that. Also, a well-researched and documented answer to a complex question can sometimes go unnoticed or receive few upvotes, while some answers to "duh!" questions rake in rep by the thousands. Case in point would be the answer to [the highest ranked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463318/how-to-exit-from-postgresql-command-line-utility-psql) with the [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) tag. (Incidentally, the dude who answered that question has access to the moderator tools on the basis of that eloquent answer alone: the answer "`\q`" earned him 9,200 rep out of 12,800 or so total. [The highest earning answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109325/postgresql-describe-table) on tag "postgresql" yielded 9,430 rep for the equally intelligent answer "`\d+ tablename`, see the manual for more info". Not to say anything to the contrary of the users in question, but it does show that the rep system has some weak spots.)

That said, I do agree with the OP that remedial action can be taken to create a more level playing field for new tags. But rather than stay with the votes-for-tags-up-to-a-level system, I would create an additional way to earn a tag badge for tags that not have had many questions posted:

- Bronze tag badge: At least 2 accepted answers where total questions <= 5.
- Silver tag badge: At least 6 accepted answers where total questions <= 25.
- Gold tag badge: At least 25 accepted answers where total questions <= 50.

The bronze tag is available almost instantly, but you have to display your skills. The silver badge requires more performance, without being out of reach. The gold badge is for the demonstrated pro. This does not address the issue of a lethargic readership that can't be bothered to vote, but it puts new tags in badge territory much sooner than the rep evaluation.

Comment: A gold badge requires *half or more* of the questions to have an accepted answer by you? This would literally preclude having more than one person with a gold badge. Or am I misunderstanding what you mean by "questions <= x"?

Comment: @jpmc26 The limits can be tweaked but the intent is that tag badges become available early on. That does not mean that everybody-and-their-grandmother should be labeled an expert. As soon as the number of questions surpasses the above gold badge limit, the regular rules will kick in and any number of users can earn badges under the votes+answers rule.

Comment: Nice idea! It could even be dynamic like `(x answer upvotes) || (y% of total tag upvotes)` where x and y are determined based on tag popularity.

Answer (score -18):

Outlier examples aside, is there some reason to believe that this effect is not already accounted for in the current badge thresholds?

Badge requirements are already arbitrary to some extent anyway. Given that one can expect a certain percentage of accepted answers to fail to garner an up-vote (from the questioner or otherwise), it seems reasonable to me to assume that the Stack Overflow staff who have set the badge requirements have already taken this into account, reducing the requirement from what it otherwise would be, were the acceptance of an answer meant to contribute to progress toward the badge.

In other words, no…I'm not sure I see the value of counting an accepted answer toward the progress of a tag badge.

In the event that the requested change is implemented, I would propose two qualifications:

- The tag badge requirement be revisited and recalibrated to attempt to preserve the current meaning of the badge (i.e. taking into account current badge holders and their average relative proportions of accepted and non-up-voted answers)
- **An acceptance of an answer be counted toward the tag badge *only* if the questioner did not also up-vote the answer (i.e. don't double-count the input from the questioner).**

**Addendum:**

For those so adamant that without the extra point toward the badge for accepted-but-not-up-voted answers, valuable contributions to Stack Exchange sites will not be made, take a moment to consider this:

It would have been trivial for SE to cause an automatic up-vote by the questioner for any question that was accepted. But they didn't do that. It seems clear that the intent is for an up-vote and an accepted answer to mean two different things. As such, it also seems clear that the tag badge, being based on up-votes, is intended to reflect the thing that up-votes mean and not the thing that accepted answers mean.

Conflating the two is just as clearly in conflict with the actual intent of the site design.

I get that it's human nature to get all hot and bothered about whether something is "fair", and I also get that it's natural to perceive a system that fails to award progress in a tag for a question that was accepted as "unfair". But the fact is, this isn't a competition and as such there's no such thing as "fair" or "unfair". Worrying about the fairness of it all is pointless.

And frankly, personally I'd rather be involved in a "helping others" site where the help is given freely, and without so much fretting about what one gets in return. The reputation and badge system is a nice add-on, and it does provide a coarse-grained mechanism to help improve the quality of the site (by restricting users until they have proven their competence and pro-social behavior). But it's already doing its job, and there's no evidence that the change being proposed here will produce any significant improvement in the quality of the site.

**If there really are people who are withholding their expertise for the sole reason that on occasion when they answer a question in manner helpful enough for the questioner to accept the answer, the question still is not awarded an up-vote, well…I feel that those people are probably not really the people the site ought to be catering to in the first place. They are "in it" for the wrong reasons.**

Comment: So basically make a change to reward those who should be earning the badge for it while also making sure that the system is recalibrated so that they do not earn it?

Comment: @DJDavid98: No, that's not what I'm saying at all. Please re-read my answer. My point is that I see no evidence that the claimed problem is a problem at all; as long as the badge requirement's original calibration takes into account the fact that not all accepted answers are up-voted (and there's every reason to believe it is), then there's no need for a change at all. If for psychological reasons, people still feel it desirable to make the change, then the change should not result in an actual change in the badge prevalence. Anyone with evidence to the contrary is welcome to present it.

Comment: The existence of the Unsung Hero badge shows how the tag badges don't account for zero-score accepted answers. For certain people this an easy badge to get, for others it can appear much more difficult. It all depends on the tags you answer questions for. I got it easily, so did the original poster I assume, but for you to get it you'd need about 50 more accepted 0 score answers without getting a single 1+ score answer in that time. This is part of what makes it harder to get certain tag badges than others. This change aims to even out the difficulty a bit, recalibrated or not.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting so many downvotes. I *completely* agree with the sentiment that "badge requirements are already arbitrary to some extent anyway". If people are complaining about the idea of a recalculation to maintain current badge scores, that's a different issue (and one I'm indifferent on), but I agree with the bulk of this answer.

Comment: @AlexisKing: yes, it is remarkably unhelpful to the discussion for folks to downvote without offering their own contribution (either another answer to provide an alternative viewpoint, or a comment here explaining their dissent). My _suspicion_ (granted, I lack any specific evidence) is that this question is generally attracting predominantly folks over-concerned with their badges (or lack thereof), and who simply disagree that _any_ perceived unfairness in the system should be accepted, as I've proposed here. But without actual communication by them, I guess we'll never know for sure.

Comment: The question is not about arbitrary requirements (which are unavoidable), it's about bias towards high-traffic tags. Well, uniform requirements do not account for any bias. Yet your main argument to not change anything is that we should assume they thought of this when they set the requirements. Since this is the only badge with real benefits - you get extra privileges and you may be seen as an authority on the subject - I think it's worth it to look into the actual data.

Comment: @knbk: the only "privilege" I'm aware of that a tag badge provides is single-vote closing of duplicates, for those with the gold-level badge. This is less a "privilege" than a mechanism to improve efficiency of housekeeping. An efficiency that is much less in need for low-traffic tags (it's impossible for there to be a problem of rampant, unclosed duplicates in a tag that gets little traffic to start with).

Comment: Doesn't really matter what you call it, that was not my point. My point is that any possible bias is not accounted for, and I think it's a good idea to look into the data to see if this bias is real and how big it is. (I also think that single-close votes are very useful in low-traffic tags to quickly close bad questions and reduce noise, but again, that's not the point.)

Comment: @knbk: that bias exists is well-established. You can investigate the data yourself if you like, but it's not relevant. Reputation itself, which is a **far** greater determining factor when it comes to privileges on the site, is subject to _huge_ bias effects: FGITW, "pioneer effect", and yes...level of traffic in the tag, to name a few. And nothing is done to attempt to address those sources of bias. So why should we ask the SO staff to invest any attention at all on such a minor issue as the tag badges? If bias is to be addressed at all, shouldn't we start with the more important areas first?

Comment: It's a reasonably isolated issue, and changing the requirements would be trivial to implement, why shouldn't it be fixed? A huge issue shouldn't stop you from fixing smaller issues.

Comment: @knbk: _"why shouldn't it be fixed"_ -- for the same reason any trivial, unimportant issue shouldn't be fixed: fixing that issue takes finite resources away from issues that actually matter. The bottom line is this: does the perceived lack of "fairness" in the awarding of the tag badges cause significant damage to the site. Would fixing the issue significantly improve the site? I don't see any evidence that the answer to either of these questions is anything but a resounding "no".

Comment: *Would fixing the issue significantly improve the site?* - it would for me, and presumably 59 other people...

Comment: @TomRedfern: really? How? Please be specific, and make sure your explanation focuses on _significant improvement_ to the site with respect to the objectively stated goals of the site, and not your own personal subjective wishes. That 59 (or even 68) other people find this question useful doesn't in any way suggest there's an actual _significant improvement_ to the success of the goals of the site that would result from this change. It just means that many people clicked the up-vote button.

Comment: The entire website is geared towards people helping people. So recognizing the people who help people mean that they will help more people. We don't need to over analyse this - it's self evident that this is true in all possible universes.

Comment: @TomRedfern: _"recognizing the people who help people mean that they will help more people"_ -- help all those people, in those low-traffic tags? How is that a significant improvement? Just how many additional people could be helped, given we're talking about a tiny fraction of the users? What proof do you have that the award of a badge is why one person helps another? What proof do you have that badge-motivated people are really the best people to foster as helpers on the site? _"We don't need to over analyse this"_ -- why not? Are you afraid that an actual analysis would refute your claims?

Comment: A tiny fraction of the users, really? We're talking about the tags people like Tom and I are active in, tags like [tag:django] and [tag:wcf]. The cumulative user base of all tags like that is far from tiny.

Comment: The proof you seem to require to accept what is basically a self evident fact about the reasons why humans do stuff is already well documented. Suffice to say, there are many reasons why we do stuff, but one of the main ones is because we are incentivised to do so. The reward system on SO is one of the ways people are incentivised to help other people. As for whether incentivised people are the *best* people to help, I don't know, but I do know that if they were not incentivised, then there would be a lot less helping going on.

Comment: @knbk: You guys are pretty funny. On the one hand, you claim that the problem is these tags are low traffic, on the other hand you claim there's lots of traffic. One the one hand, you claim that there's not enough incentive to motivate people to help. On the other hand, you claim that without the incentives that exist, people wouldn't help.

Comment: @TomRedfern: Maybe you and others are too young to remember this, but there was a time when the kind of help provided here was provided on Usenet newsgroups, email mailing lists, and even manufacturer-hosted web forums, where **zero** compensation or reward was provided. And yet, for some reason lots of people helped and were helped. Maybe times are different. Maybe the bulk of humanity will help only when they are awarded a badge. But even if you want to argue that case, you need to _demonstrate_ it, rather than just claiming your arguments as "self-evident".

Comment: No, that's just you failing to see any nuance. There is much less traffic than the top tags, which causes the bias, but there's enough traffic that all tags combined it is a significant part of the users. I personally don't think this is about motivation to help people, I have enough motivation without internet points. But fact is the points are there, and so are the badges, and the badges give you access to a handy moderator tool, and possibly more tools in the future, and it's a nice milestone either way. I think it's a good idea to adjust the requirements for the existing bias.

Comment: @knbk: _"there's enough traffic that all tags combined it is a significant part of the users"_ -- cite, please, for that broad, unsubstantiated claim. What is the threshold that defines a "low-traffic" tag? What percentage of users on Stack Overflow contribute that traffic? What percentage of posts on the site constitute that traffic? And what percentage do you consider to be "significant"? (And for the record, I have no trouble seeing nuance. But this "issue" is so miniscule, "nuance" is all it has. It's a classic [bike shed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_Law_of_Triviality))

Comment: Let's take a very conservative 10% of the weekly questions of the top tag, [tag:javascript], as a threshold for being significantly affected by the bias. That's where [tag:django] is, the tag where I'm active. That's still 13% of the weekly questions on just the first page of [popular tags](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?&tab=popular), quite a bit more if you take the next few pages into account. It probably happens at just 25% of the weekly questions of the top tag as well, which gives you 27% of the total weekly questions on the first page. That's a significant amount of traffic.

Comment: @knbk: sorry, I can't agree with your characterization of the [tag:django] tag as "low traffic". In the last 24 hours, 115 questions were asked. While I grant that's not as many questions as are asked e.g. in the [tag:java] and [tag:c#] tags, it's plenty of users and activity to produce a statistically useful input for the voting traffic. "Low traffic" would IMHO be no more than a tenth of that _at most_, and answerer Patrick pegs it at _much_ lower, considering only tags where the _total_ number of questions is fewer than 100.

Comment: I would think the traffic is low enough for a noticeable bias compared to the high traffic tags. But well, this is going nowhere without actual data. (Copying the term "low traffic" from you was wrong, better would be "medium traffic".)

Comment: @knbk: _"I would think the traffic is low enough for a noticeable bias"_ -- I wouldn't. But either way, it doesn't make sense to assume anything. If true, you should be able to demonstrate that by showing a significant difference in the number of 0-vote accepted questions. Stack Exchange has query tools that would allow you to actually compare the prevalence in two or more tags. Note that after that, the next step of analysis would be to show that the tag has a significant problem with duplicate questions that would be addressed by increasing the prevalence of gold tag badges.

Comment: *It's a classic bike shed* - It's a bike shed which you have done more to contribute to than any other user in this discussion.

Comment: @Tom: you amuse me. Do you really think the activity of trying to explain to people they are bike shedding is in and of itself bike shedding? You should study your idioms more closely.