# My other comment got deleted because of 1 "rude" comment

Tags: support

I commented on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300532/answer-acceptance-to-count-toward-tag-score) with like 15 upvotes and it was a normal comment. It said something like:

> Shouldn't accepted answers be worth more?

After that, someone responded to my comment that said something like:

> But they are worth more. You get more rep for an accepted answer.

I responded back with:

> I know that. Did you read my comment?

This could be seen as "rude". After this comment however, all the comments got deleted that had something to do with this(The conversation was only these 3 comments). Even the normal comment that got 15 upvotes got deleted. I dont see why that comment was deleted.

Is this normal or did a moderator mess up?

Comment: Comments are considered the least important medium on stack exchange, and are most appropriate for temporary remarks that could be used to improve a question or answer.  Anything else may get deleted at any time, whether it is rude, chatty, silly, social, etc.  You might notice a chat room gets created automatically when comments are lengthy, to help keep the Q&A page clean and provide a way to eventually delete the chat when no one care about it any more.

Comment: @Paul Yes, but what about the comment that got 15 upvotes and an actual good remark to the question? Any reason why that got deleted?

Comment: I am not familiar with the discussion.... but I suspect *automation*.  You don't think mods have time to pour over all the comments, do you? N of your fellow users mark it as "unconstructive" "too chatty" or whatever, and POOF, its gone.

Comment: @Paul So I'll just wait for a moderator to respond then.

Comment: Your +15 comment was flagged as *obsolete*. I deleted it because I assumed it had been addressed in the question. It was deleted *entirely independently* from the other comments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But it hasnt been addressed in the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your +15 comment was flagged as *obsolete*. I deleted it because I assumed it had been addressed in the question. It was deleted *entirely independently* from the other comments, which were flagged at a later time and handled by a different moderator.

I've re-instated the comment, as I see that it is not addressed in the question.

In general, don't get too attached to comments. They are meant to be temporary, and can get cleaned up at any time, really.

Comment: I like this answer,got here by searching for info to help my sanity;  I recently had a comment deleted, in my opinion it was not obsolete, rude or nonconstructive... regardless of context, it would be nice if it notified the poster of the comment that it was deleted and the reason. I'm still trying to figure out if i actually wrote a comment or not. I'm sure i did. Anyway just my 2 cents, thought it was uncalled for.

Comment: You only have self-deleted comments (not counting comments on deleted posts). I checked both Stack Overflow and Meta.

Comment: We delete *hundreds* of comments every day. It would be way to noisy to notify anyone about these. Again, don't get too attached to comments.