# Low rep users and accepted answers counting towards tag badges

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, tag-score

I answer a lot of questions and I myself find it frustrating to put time into an answer that contains quality and is tested. It uses jFiddle or a snippet to show the outcomes of the solution.

The bulk of questions here comes from low rep users, they aren't allowed to upvote before the have 15 rep. They need a minimum of three upvotes on their question to be allowed to upvote. Most of the times when a user posts with enough rep and you provide a good answer you'll get the double bill upvote + answer from the OP. But from low-rep users you won't get that. So I stack a lot of accepted answers with 0 upvotes and zero count to my tag counter.

I think that the answer on a question from a user with rep < 15 that is accepted should count towards your tag counter. Just getting 15 points and the eventual unsung hero badge is just not rewarding enough.

This question is different from [Answer acceptance to count toward tag score](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300532/answer-acceptance-to-count-toward-tag-score), because it only applies to users that accepts answer with a rep lower than 15.

Comment: And what about all those future visitors that *can* vote that your answers helped? You were writing those answers to be helpful for them too, right?

Answer (score 7):

Tag badges are *supposed* to be hard to get. You're talking about making it drastically easier, which is hardly fair to all the people who have already obtained gold badges.

If you want more badges, the solution is for you to *do more*, not to lower our standards for rewarding badges.

Comment: True they are hard to get, but `hardly fair to the other users` isn't really an argument against it. I do enough for it. I'm trying to put quality into the answer by explaining and commenting my code. To get 0 upvotes and an accepted answer on a somewhat impopulair domain or more complicated question than `why is this regex not working` with the first provider getting instant 5 upvotes is somewhat unfair.

Comment: I agree with @Mouser, today i answered a question which already have 3 wrong upvoted answers but my answer was last so didnt even get upvote by reviewers so yes when putting an effort n it wont return is unfair