# Tag score tracker not displaying proper value

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I noticed something that seems like it might be an issue with tag badges, where the tag points calculation does not seem to be working. It looks like it is mirroring the answer count, where it seems it should be tallying up the rep points.

[image]

Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?

If not, how do I report this as an issue?

Comment: Looking at your profile I count a score of 24 in the xamarin tag, so caching  (or me sucking at counting) would account for the difference there.  Looks fine to me.  You're simply averaging pretty close to a score of 1 per post in that tag.  That's not all that unusual.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: I was misunderstanding the tag score value. Apparently, [others have had similar misunderstanding](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288159/please-clarify-score-vs-reputation-on-tag-badge-descriptions).

Comment: As you noted - score != reputation