# What does 'score' really represent?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-score

I was [admiring the wonder that Jon Skeet's profile is](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) when I looked at his score for C#, `237,680`. Now for a mere mortal like me, I believed that the '`Score`' tab showed your *net upvotes* but after looking at this, if Jon Skeet received no downvotes and had the *minimum possible upvote amount* based on this score, his reputation, *only from the C# tag* would be well over 2 million. Now I saw that this also occurs with [Martijn Pieters' wonderful account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) where he has a score of `139,628` in the Python tag alone which again, on the basis that score is the *net upvotes* for the tag, at the very minimum, Mr Martijn would have a reputation of at ***least*** 1,396,280 if he only answered questions in the Python tag (which he doesn't, 4% of his answers go elsewhere) and only got reputation from upvotes. So what does '`Score`' really tell about someone?

Comment: not all upvotes result in rep gained.

Comment: @KevinB Oh right... so the score *does* represent net upvotes?

Comment: yes, it is net upvotes. there's a [post here about that confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288159/please-clarify-score-vs-reputation-on-tag-badge-descriptions)

Comment: @KevinB can you post that as an answer... It would be useful for people wondering about this in the future unless this is a duplicate which if it was I couldn't find 

Comment: It's not super obvious but there's some hover text, I think? I'm on my phone so I can't check.

Comment: @Catija yes I know about the hover text but the score didn't translate accordingly into the expected reputation when I looked hence this question

Comment: it's the 200 Rep cap .. if we don't have this restriction, Jon will be at 2 Million

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400092/what-does-score-really-represent?noredirect=1#comment788068_400093

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not just 2 million :D Probably more like 5 million :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: the score represents net upvotes. Some upvotes, like Kevin B said, don't result in reputation gain. An example would be Community Wiki posts, which don't award reputation for upvotes.

---

Also, keep in mind that when someone accepts your answer, you get 15 reputation, but that doesn't add to your score.

Comment: Are community wiki posts included in the score count? They are included in the post count but I don't think they are included in the score count

Comment: @NekoMusume No, they are not.

Comment: *Some upvotes, like Kevin B said, don't result in reputation gain.* Is this mainly upvotes past daily limit?

Comment: @NekoMusume Well, most of the time, yes. If you get an upvote on a non-accepted answer, then they don't award rep.

Comment: *If you get an upvote on a non-accepted answer, then they don't award rep* wait really?

Comment: @NekoMusume They do, but only if you are below the 200 Rep Cap.

Comment: @10Rep I'm not sure what you're trying to say with "*If you get an upvote on a non-accepted answer, then they don't award rep*" That's a non-sequitur. The only thing that is relevant for upvotes and rep is: 1) are you at the rep cap for the day, and 2) is your answer getting upvoted a CW answer or not

Comment: @TylerH I meant to say, if you get an upvote after rep cap, then no rep is awarded. Only accepts reward reputation after that. Sorry if I wasn't clear.